# Seaborn Heatmap With Nested Rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Given the following data frame and pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                 'B':['x','y','z','x','y','z','x','y','z'],
                 'C':['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a'],
                 'D':[7,5,3,4,1,6,5,3,1]})
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A', 'B','C'],aggfunc='sum')
table

            D
A   B   C   
a   x   a   7
        b   4
    y   a   1
        b   5
    z   a   3
b   x   a   5
    y   b   3
    z   a   1
        b   6
```

I'd like to create a heat map with divisions per indices A and B like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Styler`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.formats.style.Styler.html) in `jupyter` notebook, see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Builtin-Styles) and [notebook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/heatmap.ipynb):

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                 'B':['x','y','z','x','y','z','x','y','z'],
                 'C':['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a'],
                 'D':[7,5,3,4,1,6,5,3,1]})
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A', 'B','C'],aggfunc='sum')
table


cm = sns.light_palette("blue", as_cmap=True)
s = df.reset_index().style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
s
```

[image: heatmap]

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how I can export it as a Seaborn Heatmap or something cleaner-looking like my sample?

Comment: Ok, you can try open Jupyter notebook. for me it open new tab in browser. Then you can create new notebook (right up) and it is possible download as html, pdf, rst...